# MySQL Replication lag vs. no Lag using MariaDB

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb

I've got a Master-Master Replication set up which currently works fine. I want to add another server to the cluster. I've done all steps necessary to build the new Master (using 5.7.17 on ubuntu xenial) but as soon as I'm starting the Slave Seconds_Behind_Master always keeps increasing and the Slave never catches up.

Using exactly the same setup just with MariaDB is working fine and the Slave immediately catches up - without any hiccup. It's 10.0.29-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.

CPU Load is at zero before the Replication start, the Server is using an SSD and nothing else is installed but Mysql/MariaDB when starting the Repilcation.

Has anyone ever experienced such issue ?

Can someone tell me if I can just use MariaDB as a 1:1 replacement in a Mysql Environment so that I would have an MariaDB server in the middle of my replication setup without problems ?

Thanks !

Comment: MariaDB 10.0 as a master and MySQL 5.7 as a slave seems like it should be fine, but the other way around seems like less of a sure bet, and in master/master, of course, you have both.  What exactly do you mean by "in the middle of?"  What are the current systems running?

Comment: If you are going to be using 3 servers I suspect you'd be better off with Galera anyway. There are a couple of things not supported (do check) but overall its always nice if it doesn't matter which is the master. Ring topologies get rather confusing during error recovery when the stakes are highest. Otherwise use multi source replication to replicate in each direction from each master without log-slave-updates enabled.